# Is it possible to retrieve database values in php as the type defined in the database instead of type string?

Tags: php, database, casting, sqldatatypes

If I define a column in a mysql database as type int, my queries always return the values as type string.

Is there a way of retreiving the right type?

Comment: You mean when you `gettype($var)` in PHP it returns: string "{int}" length=x?

Comment: @DavidBarker By the way, you should rather use [`is_int()`](http://php.net/is_int).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) and the [mysqlnd driver](http://docs.php.net/mysqlnd) you can retrieve integers as type(int).

e.g.

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
setup($pdo);

foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM soFoo', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
    var_dump($row);
}

function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
        id int auto_increment,
        s varchar(32),
        t datetime,
        primary key(id)
    )');

    $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO soFoo (s,t) VALUES ('abc', Now()), (NULL, Now())");
}
```

prints

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["s"]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  ["t"]=>
  string(19) "2011-11-16 13:34:27"
}
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(2)
  ["s"]=>
  NULL
  ["t"]=>
  string(19) "2011-11-16 13:34:27"
}
```

on my machine. As you can see the `id` is returned as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can discover the type of the field by using the mysql_field_type() function and then cast the value to the appropriate type.

The first parameter is the query var and the second one is the column index in the query.

Ex:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, age FROM users");
$type  = mysql_field_type($result, 2); // Will return the type of "age"
```

Comment: I think the OP knows how to get the type. He wants the type to set when the data is retrieved from the database, not after.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure PHP will usually convert those automatically.

```
$val = $the_string_from_database;
$val *= 2;
echo $val;
```

Comment: The OP awants to know how to retreive the right type, not how to cast the type.

Comment: Yes, I know that php will convert the type once I do something with it, I would like to know if I can retreive the value as the right type without typecasting it later

Answer (score -1):

When data is returned from mySQL to PHP using standard functions the datatype is always converted to a string. You can always convert this back by using something like:

```
$int = (int) $sql_row['integer_cell'];
```

you can also use `intval()` to convert the type back.

```
$int = intval($sql_row['integer_cell'];
```

This is due in part to PHP's loose typecasting.

Comment: Still, this is not what the OP meant. In your array '$sql_row', the data is already retrieved.

Comment: Quite, and I stated that using standard PHP functions you will always return a string, answering the question. I added some extra detail to help solve a relatively well known problem.

Comment: The problem would only be solved if the OP's question was answered. Since he asks if it is possible to _retrieve_ database values as the type defined in the database, your answer is wrong. You cast the type _after_ it is retrieved.